# The Microsoft SharePoint Migration Tool

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2010, sharepoint-server, migration, content-migration

We are going to migrate from SharePoint 2010 to online, We are searching for a free tool like the Microsoft SharePoint migration tool.

Do anyone already use this tool to explain the new advantage and disadvantage?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**First of all,** you should be aware of [The new Microsoft SharePoint Migration Tool](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Blog/Introducing-the-SharePoint-Migration-Tool-from-Microsoft/ba-p/109767) doesn't support SharePoint 2010 yet, it only supports SharePoint 2013. 
**Ref:** Check the [MSFT reply](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e9f9641a-aa30-4b92-8f98-38425ac7db47/simple-migration-failed-with-the-provider-user-is-not-a-site-administrator?forum=SharePointMigrationTool) on 15/11/2017 (Planned to be supported in the future).

So, if you need to use The new Microsoft SharePoint Migration Tool, you will need to first migrate from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013.

For more details check [Upgrade process from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt493301%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

---

**The new SharePoint Migration Tool Advantages:**

- Provides a wizard-like experience, prompting you for information to simplify migrating your data from your on-premises SharePoint Server document libraries and local file shares to SharePoint Online (SPO).
- Support the smallest of migrations to large-scale migrations with support for bulk scenarios.
- Provides detailed information on the process of existing and completed migrations and task reports to help identify and resolve issues that may have occurred during the migration process.

**The new SharePoint Migration Tool Disadvantages:**

- Only support to migrate from SharePoint 2013 to either SharePoint Online or OneDrive for Business!
- List migration is not supported, only SharePoint Server document libraries and local file shares. (Planned to be supported in 2018)
- Not suitable for complex and advanced migration scenarios.
- Migrate from SharePoint On-prem to another SharePoint On-prem is not supported.
- Migrate from SharePoint online to another SharePoint online is not supported.
- No options for custom metadata mapping.
- ADFS authentication isn't supported (Planned to be supported in 2018).

---

**For alternatives check**

- [Migrate to SharePoint Online.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Migrate-to-SharePoint-Online-d8c6ce52-f8a2-4661-97f7-45e49351bdb9)
- [Upload on-premises content to SharePoint Online.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Upload-on-premises-content-to-SharePoint-Online-555049c6-15ef-45a6-9a1f-a1ef673b867c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
- [How to Migrate from SP 2007 On-Premises to O365?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231663/how-to-migrate-from-sp-2007-on-premises-to-o365/231665#231665)

---

**For more details, check**

- [The new SharePoint Migration Tool from Microsoft.](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Blog/Introducing-the-SharePoint-Migration-Tool-from-Microsoft/ba-p/109767)
- [Introducing the SharePoint Migration Tool.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introducing-the-SharePoint-Migration-Tool-9c38f5df-300b-4adc-8fac-648d0215b5f7)
- [How to use the SharePoint Migration Tool.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-use-the-SharePoint-Migration-Tool-65462df1-42fe-40cf-88f7-e39f82f5130f)
- [How the SharePoint Migration Tool works.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-the-SharePoint-Migration-Tool-works-5b22e9e3-9548-442e-bf21-bd753b72bffa?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Hi Qassas,Thanks for sharing this information. Do you know whether this migration tool keeps default metadata columns intact, like created by, created date etc.?

Comment: @PS Yes, brother, It will preserve those kinds of metadata like the created by, modified by ... etc! (No options for custom metadata mapping yet). check also my answer here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232389/migrate-sharepoint-onprem-to-office-365/232392#232392

Comment: Oh that's great. Now atleaset we will need not to use 3rd party tool. Hope list migration will also get supported soon.

Comment: @PS By the way, some of the new features  will be added and some of the limitations will be overcome in the earlier of 2018 based on MSFT feedback