# Migrate SharePoint onprem to office 365

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, content-migration, migrate

We have SharePoint online as well as on premises in our organisation. Recently we have decided to use only online. I know there are third party tools such as share-gate or metalogix  which allows as to do this. But our contents on the on prem is pretty small and we do not want to move all the details to the online plat form. Plus there is the cost factor as well.

I know that we can copy the contents manualy by then there will be a problem of metadata,created by, modified by and date fields. What is the alternative ?
if you could provide some documentation or a step by step guide to do this that will be great.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using [The Free SharePoint Migration Tool from Microsoft](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Blog/Introducing-the-SharePoint-Migration-Tool-from-Microsoft/ba-p/109767).

- It provides a wizard-like experience, prompting you for information to simplify migrating your data from your on-premises SharePoint Server document libraries and local file shares to SharePoint Online (SPO).
- It supports the smallest of migrations to large-scale migrations with support for bulk scenarios.
- It provides detailed information on the process of existing and completed migrations and task reports to help identify and resolve issues that may have occurred during the migration process.
- It will preserve those kinds of metadata like the created by, modified by  ... etc! (No options for custom metadata mapping yet).

> **Note:**  The new Microsoft SharePoint Migration Tool doesn't support SharePoint 2010 yet, it only supports SharePoint 2013 (Planned to be
>   supported in the future). For more details check
>   [The Microsoft SharePoint Migration Tool](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232142/the-microsoft-sharepoint-migration-tool/232143#232143)

**For more details check**

- [Introducing the SharePoint Migration Tool.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introducing-the-SharePoint-Migration-Tool-9c38f5df-300b-4adc-8fac-648d0215b5f7)
- [The Microsoft SharePoint Migration Tool](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232142/the-microsoft-sharepoint-migration-tool/232143#232143)
- [How to use the SharePoint Migration Tool.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-use-the-SharePoint-Migration-Tool-65462df1-42fe-40cf-88f7-e39f82f5130f)
- [How the SharePoint Migration Tool works.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-the-SharePoint-Migration-Tool-works-5b22e9e3-9548-442e-bf21-bd753b72bffa?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Thanks M.Qassas, Will this allow you to migrate the whole site, document library or list ?

Comment: you are welcome, It only supports SharePoint Server document libraries and local file shares as a source even List migration is not supported but planned to be supported in 2018! as you said you have pretty small documents so I suggest this as a free tool especially it will preserve those kinds of metadata like the created by, modified by :)

Comment: So currently there are no way to migrate the lists other than copy paste or use third party tools like share-gate or metalogix ? again copy past will have issues with metadata right?

Comment: there are other alternatives rather than the 3rd part tools that I have mentioned in another thread https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231663/how-to-migrate-from-sp-2007-on-premises-to-o365/231665#231665, but in my opinion, it's good chance to try this tool with the document library to preserve the metadata and also to try something new :) besides this try the alternatives in my above link for lists!

Comment: By the way @Rinu , before you try to use the SPMT, I also suggest checking the disadvantage of SPMT at this thread https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232142/the-microsoft-sharepoint-migration-tool/232143#232143

Comment: I am pretty confidant the about the document libraries using the SharePoint Migration Tool. But i am concerned about the list. We have been using some of the list for as long as 10 years and would like keep meta data such as created by ,dates etc. i am unable to find proper examples of  PowerShell migration APIs or Office 365 Migration API. would you happened to have any more reference for the same ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are not enough refs but I will try to search for additional Refs. also if you find difficulties to use alternatives or you don't have time so you need to use readymade tool so go ahead with 3rd party tools where you can try it first as a trail to check its capabilities! by the way, the list migration in SPMT is planned to be supported in the earlier of 2018

Answer (score 2):

Before deciding on a migration strategy, remember to perform an analysis of your current environment.

Below is a good article which should help you in understanding about migrating SharePoint onprem to office 365. It also provide several methods about upgrading to Office 365 or SharePoint Online, which may be useful for you:

http://en.share-gate.com/blog/migrate-to-office-365-sharepoint-supported-scenarios

You can migrate content from on-premises to online using Windows PowerShell cmdlets for SPO Migration:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Upload-on-premises-content-to-SharePoint-Online-555049c6-15ef-45a6-9a1f-a1ef673b867c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

You can also refer to below article for more information about using windows powershell when migrate SharePoint onprem to office 365 :

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nishants/2015/07/18/using-windows-powershell-cmdlets-for-sharepoint-online-o365spo-migration/

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the  Import Service in Office 365 to move your data files from your own premises SharePoint Server site to SharePoint Online.

Get help from this article to migrate from [SharePoint On Premises to SharePoint Online Office 365](http://expert-advice.org/2017/02/sharepoint-2010-on-premises-to-sharepoint-online-office-365-migration/).

You can also use third party tools that are available to migrate SharePoint on premises to Office 365 as per your requirements. Here is a [list](http://www.topsharepoint.com/content-migration-tools-for-sharepoint).