# Migrate SharePoint 2016 on-prem to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, 2016, document-migration

I have a SharePoint 2016 on-premise environment with around 750 GB of data stored in document libraries. Our company has recently purchased O365/SharePoint Online.
How do I move/migrate these document libraries to SharePoint Online, without using 3rd-party products like Sharegate?

The SharePoint Migration Tool seems to support only SharePoint 2013 on-prem.
Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes,** you are right, the `Sharepoint Migration tool` only supports SharePoint 2013 yet.

For more details about Check my answer at [The Microsoft SharePoint Migration Tool](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232142/the-microsoft-sharepoint-migration-tool/232143#232143)

---

**Workaround**

Using **3rd party tool** like:

- Dockit Migrator
- Sharegate
- Metalogix
- AvePoint

Check also additional workarounds at my answer [How to Migrate from SP 2007 On-Premises to O365?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231663/how-to-migrate-from-sp-2007-on-premises-to-o365/231665#231665)

Comment: Thanks Mohamed for your quick response. Would it be possible to use powershell to migrate?

Comment: @JackSparrow Welcome:) In fact, it's a big data size that about 750 GB, so I suggest using 3rd party tool to ensure that the data & metadata & versions, permission ..etc will be migrated efficiency, BTW, you can use the trial version to check the capability of that tools

Comment: But if you don't have a budget you can check the additional workaround at my answer https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/231663/how-to-migrate-from-sp-2007-on-premises-to-o365/231665#231665

Comment: Based on your experience, which of these products would you suggest. We need to move all the docs with metadata and versions. Your post has been really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @JackSparrow Try to use Sharegate! Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you to close this question!

Answer (score 2):

As usual the answer is: it depends

If you do not have any requirements regarding keeping metadata and permissions than powershell absolutly is an option.
Otherwise I will recommend the same tools as above. They just work and contains the options you'll need

Comment: Thanks Kasper. Yes, We need the metadata, versions and permissions.